# "The victory, within four days, was just reward" - why not "was just a reward"?

Tags: articles, idioms, idiom-request

[Source](http://epaperbeta.timesofindia.com/Article.aspx?eid=31808&articlexml=ALL-ROUND-ASHWIN-TAKES-INDIA-TO-HISTORIC-WIN-25072016001027)

> The victory, within four days, **was just reward** for skipper Kohli's insistence on playing five bowlers. Kohli led the way with a superb 200.

We did not use **was just a reward** because **was just reward** has an idiomatic usage.What do you say?

Comment: Just as the meaning of "justice". Someone worked hard for something and finally earned it. Justice was served.

Comment: A better question is, "why not '**a just reward**'?"

Comment: Note that in the phrase "just reward", "just" *intensifies* the reward. By contrast, in the phrase "just a reward", "just" *diminishes* or *belittles* the reward.

Comment: "just" as in "fair", not "just" as in "only"

Comment: In general, when you encounter a word which makes no sense in some context, looking up all its definitions is a good practice.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

The meaning of "just" here is adjectival: "well-merited", "well-earned". In short, he earned the reward, therefore the reward was "just".

I also half-expected an indefinite article there, but in another position:

> The victory, within four days, was **a** just reward for skipper Kohli's insistence on playing five bowlers. Kohli led the way with a superb 200.

However, it seems like "reward" can be used as an uncountable noun, in which case there's no need for the article.

[image]

Indeed, the Oxford Learner's Dictionary indicates that the noun can be used as [countable, uncountable], and [quotes an example](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/reward_1):

> Winning the match **was just reward** for the effort the team had made.

Comment: I would like to edit to specify *Oxford Learner's Dictionary* because it is substantially different from the "[ODO](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com),"  for  example. Oftentimes these learners dictionaries are way oversimplified and dumb downed. You might respond that only the learners dictionary specifies that *reward* here is a non-count noun. And I might ask: is there any meaningful difference between the two? Also, can we use *reward* in the OP's sentence w/o the modifier *just*? If so, would it be a non-count or count noun? In fact, are you sure that *just reward* is a non-count noun?

Comment: Is it possible that *just reward* is a count noun with no article?

Comment: @AlanCarmack: A count noun can never appear without a determiner (including articles "the" and "a", and possessives like "your" and "my", and quantifiers like "much"). So if you consider "just reward" as a count noun then it cannot occur in the syntax used here.

Comment: By the way, the use of "reward" as an uncountable noun is attested since the 17th century, and can be seen in various translations of the Hebrew scriptures such as at Deut 10:17, Psa 15:5, 19:11, including the KJV, the ASV and Darby's version.

Comment: Actually @user21820 there are many times when a singular count noun can be used  without a determiner. 'He is captain of the ship', 'Dog eats mouse', 'hurricane ahead', 'stir in egg, et al. I am not asking the question for my benefit, but for that of CK (CowperKettle).

Comment: @AlanCarmack: The first is used as a title; different grammar. Same for "king" and "queen". The kind of article dropping in "Dog eats mouse" is found mainly in news headings, and is not grammatically proper.

Comment: @user21820 Great, you seem to "know all the answers." As a matter of fact, so do I. My question was directed specifically to CowperKettle. Perhaps you could let CK come up with a response.

Comment: @AlanCarmack: Lol. This forum isn't a one-on-one contest. You asked a question in a comment. Anyone is free to reply. If someone else wishes to respond to either of us, they can too. Since you added to your comment... "hurricane ahead" and "stir in egg" both occur in the same kind of situation where it is arguably useful to shorten the phrase and naturally articles are the first to go, followed by the equative verb in the former. =)

Comment: This answer could be greatly improved it it included the word "justice", and that in this context "just" is different from "only". If the OP confounded the two, this answer as it is now, might not clear it up enough.

Comment: For a discussion of English *usage*, the pretty graphs about "countable nouns" etc might be useful. But to the current question by a *language learner*, they are wildly tangential to the question asked.

Comment: I admit to all the possible insuffiencies. Feel free to post add-on answers, it is welcomed here!

Comment: @user21820 Not forum but QA site. Discussions in comments are secondary to the purpose of the site and are in fact undesirable if they become extended as this one seems to.

Comment: @JAB: The purpose of this site is to help English language learners. My comments were in response to a comment by Alan that I deem unhelpful to beginners, so if you don't like them I think you're doing the learners here a disservice. I didn't post another answer for the obvious reason that my comments were not directly related to the question, but merely were meant to explain why CowperKettle's expectation of an article for a countable noun is correct.

Comment: If I say "he is just friend" instead of "a friend" then I am not belittling my friend, though both are grammatical?

Answer (score 2):

This usage of "just reward" is in parallel to the expression "just deserts."

"Just deserts" means "getting the comeuppance you rightfully deserve."

> Losing his business was just deserts for his unethical practices.

https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/just_deserts

"Just rewards" is the complement -- getting the *reward* you rightfully deserve.

In both cases, "just" is used to refer to "justice."

"Just a reward" means "merely a reward."

> The money was just a reward; the real payoff was the satisfaction.

I always used the spelling "just desserts," but I was corrected by Wiki.

http://grammarist.com/spelling/just-deserts-just-desserts/

Comment: If I say "he is just friend" instead of "a friend" then I am not belittling my friend, though both are grammatical?

Comment: The expression "just a friend" means "merely or only a friend." That meay or may not be belittling, depending on the context.

Comment: The teenager was asked if the fellow she had been seen with was a beau. "Nah," she said, "he's just a friend."

Comment: In  another context, the clerk in City Hall asked the couple who were applying for a marriage license, "Are you siblings, parent and child, first cousins, aunt and uncle, niece or nephew ... " The groom interrupted and said, "Oh, not at all. We're just friends." Probably one of these uses is intended to be more belittling than the other.